# Gray-scale SEM Microscopy Image to Beautiful Color Rendering?

Tags: image, colors, rendering

do you know of any Open Source software that could help me perform such a thing: converting a gray-scale image to an eye-catching colorful rendering. I was thinking about ImageMagick (along with EBImage package) or Gimp while resorting to a Script-Fu. Also, being able to automate the process would be great.

I thank you for sharing a fraction of your valuable time in answering my question.

Good day,

Raphael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You looking for LookUp Tables (LUT). See [ImageJ wiki](http://imagejdocu.tudor.lu/doku.php?id=gui%3aimage%3alookup_tables).

Just install ImageJ or it's Fiji distribution, open your image and select **Image > Lookup Tables > *Choose one nice***. If your image is not really grayscale (not one-channel), program raises an exception like *LUTs cannot be assigned to RGB images*. If so, select **Image > Type > 8-bit** and apply LUT again.

Use macros or language bindings (I use [Jython](http://fiji.sc/wiki/index.php/Jython_Scripting)) for automation.